# SocketAsyncEventArgs ReceiveAsync Limitations (arg.Complete not called)

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

We have a pretty standard TCP implementation of SocketAsyncEventArgs (no real difference to the numerous  examples you can google).

We have a load testing console app (also using SocketAsyncEventArgs) that sends x many messages per second. We use thread spinning to introduce mostly accurate intervals within the 1000ms to send the message (as opposed to sending x messages as fast as possible and then waiting for the rest of the 1000ms to elapse).

The messages we send are approximately 2k in size, to which the server implementation responds (on the same socket) with a pre-allocated HTTP OK 200 response.

We would expect to be able to send 100's if not 1000's of messages per second using SocketAsyncEventArgs.  We found that with a simple blocking TcpListener/TcpClient we were able to process ~150msg/s.  However, even with just 50 messages per second over 20 seconds, we lose 27 of the 1000 messages on average.

This is a TCP implementation, so we of course expected to lose no messages; especially given such a low throughput.

I'm trying to avoid pasting the entire implementation (~250 lines), but code available on request if you believe it helps.  My question is, what *load* should we expect from SAEA?  Given that we preallocate separate pools for Accept/Receive/Send args which we have confirmed are never starved, why do we not receive an `arg.Complete` callback for each message?

*NB: No socket errors are witnessed during execution*

**Responses to comments**:

@usr: Like you, we were concerned that our implementation may have serious issues cooked in.  To confirm this we took the downloadable zip from [this popular Code Project example project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod).  We adapted the load test solution to work with the new example and re-ran our tests.  We experienced **EXACTLY** the same results using someone else's code (which is primarily why we decided to approach the SO community).

We sent 50 msg/sec for 20 seconds, both the code project example and our own code resulted in an average of 973/1000 receive operations.  Please note, we took our measurements at the most rudimentary level to reduce risk of incorrect monitoring.  That is, we used a static int with `Interlocked.Increment` on the `onReceive` method - `onComplete` is only called for asynchronous operations, `onReceive` is invoked both by `onComplete` and when `!willRaiseEvent`.

All operations performed on a single machine using the loopback address.

Having experienced issues with two completely different implementations, we then doubted our load test implementation.  We confirmed via Wireshark that our load test project did indeed send the traffic as expected (fragmentation was present in the pcap log, but wireshark indicated the packets were reassembled as expected).  My networking understanding at low levels is weaker than I'd like, I admit, but given the amount of fragmentation nowhere near matches the number of missing messages, we are for now assuming the two are not related.  As I udnerstand it, fragmentation should be handled at a lower layer, and completely abstracted at our level of API calls.

@Peter,

Fair point, in a normal networking scenario such level of timing accuracy would be utterly pointless.  However, the waiting is very simple to implement and wireshark confirms the timing of our messages to be as accurate as the pcap log's precision allows.  Given we are only testing on loopback (the same code has been deployed to Azure cloud services also which is the intended destination for the code once it is production level, but the same if not worse results were found on A0, A1, and A8 instances), we wanted to ensure some level of throttling.  The code would easily push 1000 async args in a few ms if there was no throttling, and that is not a level of stress we are aiming for.

I would agree, given it is a TCP implementation, there must be a bug in our code.  Are you aware of any bugs in [the linked Code Project example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod)?  Because it exhibits the same issues as our code.

Comment: "no real difference to the numerous examples you can google" That means it is likely to be deeply broken :)

Comment: Are you aware that TCP is not message based? There is no such things as receiving a message with TCP. Your code has a bug which cannot be found without it being here. Short code is required, though.

Comment: "We use thread spinning to introduce mostly accurate intervals within the 1000ms" -- this is likely at least _part_ of your problem. In any case, there's no point in doing it; network I/O doesn't have even as good timing characteristics as Windows thread scheduling, so all your efforts are wasted. `Receive/SendAsync()` certainly should be able to perform as well as any other `Socket` API. If you are _losing_ data with TCP, then you've got a bug in your code, period. Most likely, you're getting the 150 msg/s you expected, but ignoring 2/3rds of them due to your bug.

Comment: Sorry to have offended you. That was not at all the intention. Trying to help you here by setting expectations right. I answer multiple questions a week about broken TCP code. You wouldn't believe what I have seen.

Comment: Are you aware that a receive operation can receive multiple messages at once? The code in that codeproject article does not seem to handle this case.

Comment: @usr, that may well be the case. It's is a colleagues code that is experiencing the issue but I will add additional checks for message size. Measuring total byte throughput makes much more sense than measuring receive operations. Apologies for misinterpreting the previous comments, will post back with progress.

Comment: @usr, as predicted the buffers did contain multiple messages.  We now need to work out how it is we're going to marry messages back together (TCP guarantees sequence of delivery, but in using multiple SAEA's we lose that guarantee through threading). Feel free to mention the possibility of receiving more than one message in a single receive op as an answer and I'll get this closed and marked up.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @usr, as predicted the buffers did contain multiple messages. We now need to work out how it is we're going to marry messages back together (TCP guarantees sequence of delivery, but in using multiple SAEA's we lose that guarantee through threading).

The best solution is to abandon custom TCP protocols. Use HTTP and protocol buffers for example. Or, web services. For all of this there are fast and easy to use asynchronous libraries available. Assuming this is not what you want:

Define a message framing format. For example, prepend `BitConvert.GetBytes(messageLengthInBytes)` to each message. That way you can deconstruct the stream.

Comment: Unfortunately @usr, none of the above applies to us.  The messages are variable length, sent by a third party product.  We have to receive these messages, process/persist them, and respond to each (ACK style). We cannot add length markers to the messages, nor can we convert these messages to a HTTP transmission.

Comment: Well, the 3rd party protocol surely allows to do separate messages. You just cannot rely on TCP to do that. I don't know what to recommend given that the protocol is unknown to me. But this should not be a fundamentally hard problem.

Comment: The 3rd party hardware outputs variable length xml documents. If we use a single SocketAsyncEventArg we can stack our byte arrays and of course have no issue splitting the stream up into the separate documents.  If we use multiple SAEA's, we cannot guarantee the byte array blocks are persisted (in memory or otherwise) in the order they were sent/received, so marrying together broken xml documents becomes an issue.  Have you come across issues like that before or have any recommendations?  For now we're testing load against a single arg.

Comment: I'd hook up a NetworkStream to the socket and have the XML APIs pull from that (potentially asynchronously, but that is not required). I'd delete all the event based IO stuff. That only exists to save a small amount of CPU usage. Compared to the XML processing it is negligible.